# Vector fields on $[0,1]^n$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

I have a simple problem in differential geometry.
I need to study differential dynamical systems and vector fields on the closed hypercube $I^n = [0,1]^n$ (where $n \in \mathbb{N}$) and I don't know how can I do it *properly*.
What I mean is that $I^n$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (neither a smooth submanifold with boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$), so: **how can I define correctly  vector fields on $I^n$** ?

For example, I know that as $I^n$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk $D^{n-1}$, we can define a smooth structure on $I^n$ using the fact that $D^{n-1}$ is a smooth submanifold with boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
First, I am wondering why this way of doing should be chosen rather than another one and what differences does this induces on vector fields on $I^n$ (compare to another choice of smooth structure) ? Second, in this example, $I^n$ becomes a smooth manifold **with boundary**: does this *affects* (in any manner) the result about vector fields (e.g. existence of solutions of the associated ODE) ?

Little precision: I am not used to study dynamical systems and ODE, so please be indulgent.
Thank you !

Comment: Could you describe in what way this is problematic? How do you make the difference between vector fields and smooth (for any given order of differentiability) maps from $I^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$? For ODE you can take the interior as open domain, no problem of defining derivatives and vector fields there. The only thing that could be "interesting" is vector fields that can not be extended to some small open neighborhood of $I^n$ with some given regularity/smoothness.

Comment: I would say that a map $f$ from $I^n$ to $\bb R^n$ is smooth if I can find a smooth map $F$ from an open subset $U$ of $\bb R^n$ such that $I^n \subset U$ and such that $F$ coincide with $f$ on $I^n$. However, for vector fields, don't we need tangent spaces ? As $I^n$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\bb R^n$, how do we obtain tangent spaces ? That's where begin all my questions about the different smooth structures possible on $I^n$.

Comment: For the ODE, in doing so, what happens to points on the boundary (if we focus only on the interior) ?

Comment: The framework in differential geometry is a cell complex. Cubes and tetrahedrons are the archetypal examples. And yes, most of the fun is where the function or vector field is less regular on the boundary, possibly even graded  by the dimension of the faces.